# How to properly bind a trait to its impl when the later one has implicit parameters

Tags: scala, playframework, guice, reactivemongo

[Please forgive me for the long question, I'm still learning to Scala.]

I'm trying to bind a generic trait to its generic impl who has implicit parameters. Here's the cleanup code:

```
trait PersistenceService[T <: SomeOtherClass] { 
  def persist(record: T): Future[Unit]
}

class MongoPersistenceService[T <: SomeOtherClass] @Inject()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext, tag: ClassTag[T]) extends PersistenceService[T] {
  val collectionName: String = tag.runtimeClass.getSimpleName
  val databaseName = "someDatabase"

  def db: Future[DefaultDB] = MongoConnectionWrapper.getMongoConnection("mongodb://127.0.0.1", "27017")
                              .flatMap(_.database(databaseName))

  def collection: Future[BSONCollection] = db.map(_.collection(collectionName))

  def persist(record: T): Future[Unit] = {
    val result = for {
      col <- collection
      writeResult <- col.insert(record)
    } yield writeResult
    result.recoverWith {
                         case WriteResult.Code(11000) => throw RecordAlreadyExistsException(record,
                                                                                            "")
                       }.map(_ => ())
  }

  def read(id: BSONObjectID): Future[T] = {
    val query = BSONDocument("_id" -> id)
    val readResult: Future[T] = for {
      coll <- collection
      record <- coll.find(query).requireOne[T]
    } yield record

    readResult.recoverWith {
                             case NoSuchResultException => throw RecordNotFoundException(id)
                           }
  }
}
```

I'm using Play, ReactiveMongo and ScalaGuice (all latest versions). So here's my main Module class binding everything:

```
class Module(env: Environment, config: Configuration) extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {
  def configure(): Unit = {
    bind[PersistenceService[_]].to[MongoPersistenceService[_]] // Also tried with specific class instead of _ but not working either
  }
}
```

And let's say I have one of my controller with dependency on PersistenceService like this:

```
class PersistenceServiceController @Inject()(val PersistenceService: PersistenceService[Bar], cc ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) { ... }
```

And the model (as you can probably guess) with its implicits Reader/Writer:

```
case class Bar() extends SomeOtherClass() {}
object Bar {
  implicit object BarReader extends BSONDocumentReader[Bar] {
    def read(doc: BSONDocument): Bar = { ... }
  }
  implicit object BarWriter extends BSONDocumentWriter[Bar] {
    def write(bar: Bar): BSONDocument = { ... }
  }
}
```

With all this stuffs, I'm getting the following runtime exception:

```
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:
1) No implementation for reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocumentReader<Bar> was bound.
  while locating reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocumentReader<Bar>
    for the 2nd parameter of MongoPersistenceService.<init>(MongoPersistenceService.scala:15)
  at Module.configure(Module.scala:14) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> Module)
2) No implementation for reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocumentWriter<Bar> was bound.
  while locating reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocumentWriter<Bar>
    for the 3rd parameter of persistence.MongoPersistenceService.<init>(MongoPersistenceService.scala:15)
  at Module.configure(Module.scala:14) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> Module)
3) No implementation for scala.reflect.ClassTag<Bar> was bound.
  while locating scala.reflect.ClassTag<Bar>
    for the 5th parameter of MongoPersistenceService.<init>(MongoPersistenceService.scala:15)
  at Module.configure(Module.scala:14) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> Module)
```

So clearly, the stuffs my class MongoPersistenceService should get in the execution context are missing some how. I understand that Play is kind of magically providing the execution context when you setup your stuffs properly with guice. But in that case, looks like it's not working.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm feeling bad about this one but the error message was pretty obvious to find the issue. To fix it, I had to manually bind an impl for `BSONDocumentReader[Bar]`, `BSONDocumentWriter[Bar]` and `ClassTag[Bar]`.

I since refactored my code to something much simpler.
But wanted to let know other people what was the issue.